# find method on column by name or index jumping the first cell on the DataBodyRange

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Definições]

I have that table in the sheet "Definições" and when searching for "Carregamento para" on the "Norma" column it jump the A2 cell for some reason... I mean the find does not mentioned the A2 cell it goes straight to A5.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Definições")

Dim tbl1 As ListObject
Set tbl1 = ws.ListObjects("Tabela1")

Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell1a As Range
Set cell1a = tbl1.ListColumns("Norma").DataBodyRange
Set cell1 = tbl1.ListColumns("Norma").DataBodyRange.Find(What:="Carregamento para", After:=tbl1.DataBodyRange.Cells(cell1a.Row - 1, 1))
Debug.Print "DataBodyRange:" & tbl1.ListColumns("Norma").DataBodyRange.Address
Debug.Print "A2.Value:" & ws.Range("A2").Value
Debug.Print cell1.Address
Debug.Print cell1a.Address
End Sub
```

The Immediate window is returning this. Using header name `"Norma"` of the index `1` on the  `ListColumns` it's the same result.

```
DataBodyRange:$A$2:$A$7
A2.Value:Carregamento para
$A$5
$A$2:$A$7
```

Any idea where the error is... Did try to search for something similar in google but nothing about this kind of error/bug ...

Comment: See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144128)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396)   - specifically the `After` parameter. _The cell after which you want the search to begin ... the search begins after this cell_ and _If you do not specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range._

Comment: Also not the bit abour _The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method._ - if you don't specify these you may get unexpected results

Comment: Have you try with the After:= argument ? Cause i had it before and i just place it more simply to be easy to check... with the after argument does not work as well... But any way i will update the code with the after argument and test it again and place here

Comment: code updated... and still shows the same

Comment: humm i have added to the code a  `cell1.FindPrevious` after the `set cell1`line and still shows the same A5 result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Find` method has a optional parameter `After`.  From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144128)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396)

> After: The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface.
>
> Notice that After must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell.
>
> If you do not specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range.

In order to *start* the search at the first cell of a range, specify `After` as the *last* cell in the range:  in your case that would be (since you already have `Set cell1a = tbl1.ListColumns("Norma").DataBodyRange` lets use that)

```
After:=cell1a.Cells(cell1a.Cells.Count)
```

Note also the Remaks section of the help

> The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. **To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.**

Comment: well thanks it does work indeed but... why it does work ? i mean, `Cell1a.Cells.Count` will return the total rows the column has (in this case `6`), also why or how is `cells(number)` a range ?

Comment: so are you saying that since the cell is looking after the last cell it will move back again to the beginning, to **re**start the search ?

Comment: `Cells` with a single parameter is an index into the range, counting accross rows, then down columns.  Cell.Count is the total number of Cells in a range.  Therefore `cell1a.Cells(cell1a.Cells.Count)` is the cell whose index is the taotal number of cells in the range, ie the _last_ cell

Comment: Yes, (that's also in the linked docs) _When the search reaches the end of the specified search range, it wraps around to the beginning of the range_